# CSS 2 background images (with x width) on either side of 1024px footer

Tags: css, background-image

I have a footer that is 1024px in width with a background image 1024px by 482px.

I want to put an x-repeating background to the left of it and an x-repeating background to the right of it. How do I do this?

This is what I have:

```
.footer {
background:
  url("footerleft-bg.png") repeat-x,
  url("footerright-bg.png") repeat-x 0 0 #fff;
height:482px;
width:100%;
}
```

But it makes the left background image completely cover the right one.

Comment: You can't do that. A repeating background image will always repeat across the whole width or height of a box. It's not possible to have one image cover the left half and another image cover the right half.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

## [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3739710)

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10em;
    background: black;
}
footer:before, footer:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%; bottom: 5%;
    width: 40%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 1px 100%;
    content: '';
}
footer:before { left: 5%; background-image: linear-gradient(crimson, black); }
footer:after { right: 5%; background-image: linear-gradient(black, dodgerblue); }
```

However, there is no way to do it without using nested elements or pseudo-elements. A background repeats itself or it doesn't. It doesn't repeat itself just on an interval from point A to point B (though I would sometimes find that useful as well).

Comment: I **knew** you were going to answer this :) +1

Comment: I was going to post a similar solution, but you beat me to it. :P

Comment: Yes, that is correct. IE7 does not support pseudo-elements, so child elements would have to be used. But IE7 doesn't support multiple backgrounds (as the question specifies) either.

Answer (score 1):

CSS2 does not support multiple background images. You'll need to nest another HTML element to make this work.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multiple_backgrounds.html

Comment: Even if this was in CSS3, there's no way to achieve what he wants using multiple background images. But yeah, you're right about nesting another HTML element.

Comment: I don't think it was meant like "CSS2", but like "CSS, 2 background images...".